# Edit text columns

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have a text file (the first two lines are character spacings):

> ```
>          1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
> 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
> ATOM      1  N1  SPINA   3      30.616  29.799  14.979  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM      2  N1  SPINA   3      28.146  28.381  13.950  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM      3  N1  SPINA   3      27.605  28.239  14.037  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM      4  N1  SPINA   3      30.333  29.182  15.464  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM      5  N1  SPINA   3      29.608  29.434  14.333  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM      6  N1  SPINA   3      29.303  29.830  13.317  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM      7  N1  SPINA   3      28.963  31.116  13.472  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM      8  N1  SPINA   3      28.859  28.743  13.828  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM      9  N1  SPINA   3      29.699  30.575  14.564  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM     10  N1  SPINA   3      29.518  29.194  15.301  1.00 20.00      S    N
> ```

I want to edit it and make it like:

> ```
>          1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
> 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
> ATOM      1 N001 SPINA   3      30.616  29.799  14.979  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM      2 N002 SPINA   3      28.146  28.381  13.950  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM      3 N003 SPINA   3      27.605  28.239  14.037  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM      4 N004 SPINA   3      30.333  29.182  15.464  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM      5 N005 SPINA   3      29.608  29.434  14.333  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM      6 N006 SPINA   3      29.303  29.830  13.317  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM      7 N007 SPINA   3      28.963  31.116  13.472  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM      8 N008 SPINA   3      28.859  28.743  13.828  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM      9 N009 SPINA   3      29.699  30.575  14.564  1.00 20.00      S    N  
> ATOM     10 N010 SPINA   3      29.518  29.194  15.301  1.00 20.00      S    N
> ```

The number of spaces between each column are important and the list of atoms needs to go up to 190 (N001-N190). Thus I would like to replace characters 13-16 (" N1 ") in file 1 with ("N001") and keep the remainder of the file in the original spacing.

Comment: Nice. What did you try so far? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need 10 long lines of sample input to demonstrate the problem or the solution:

```
$ cat file
ATOM      1  N1  SPINA   3
ATOM      2  N1  SPINA   3
ATOM     10  N1  SPINA   3

$ awk '{print substr($0,1,12) sprintf("N%03d",$2) substr($0,17)}' file
ATOM      1 N001 SPINA   3
ATOM      2 N002 SPINA   3
ATOM     10 N010 SPINA   3
```

I'm assuming we could use $2 as the numeric part of the 3rd field. It seems to increment sequentially with your line numbers. Using NR might be an alternative. If neither of those is actually what you want, post some more representative sample input/output.

Also, note that any solution that involves assigning to a field (e.g. `$3=...`) WILL cause awk to recompile the line using the value of OFS as the field separator and so will change your spacing.

Oh, and if those 2 initial lines of character spacings are really present in your files, this is the tweak:

```
$ cat file
         1         2
12345678901234567890123456
ATOM      1  N1  SPINA   3
ATOM      2  N1  SPINA   3
ATOM     10  N1  SPINA   3

$ awk 'NR>2{$0 = substr($0,1,12) sprintf("N%03d",$2) substr($0,17)} 1' file
         1         2
12345678901234567890123456
ATOM      1 N001 SPINA   3
ATOM      2 N002 SPINA   3
ATOM     10 N010 SPINA   3
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do thanks. The two inital lines of character spacings were just to communicate the problem and weren't in the file.

Answer (score 1):

**Try :**

```
$ awk '{$3=substr($3,1,1) sprintf("%03d",$2)}1' OFS=\\t file
```

**Note : OFS will be tab**

**If you want to try this on a `Solaris/SunOS` system, change `awk` to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` , `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` , or `nawk`**

**--edit--**

if you want to increment with line

```
$ awk '{$3=substr($3,1,1) sprintf("%03d",NR)}1' OFS=\\t file
```

Comment: This worked well for the numbering however I wanted to maintain the initial spacing in the file. If I delete the OFS=\\t part of the command the output is now space delimited however I need to keep the exact number of spaces between characters in the original file. Is there a way to do this. P.s. could you talk me through the command if you have time? And thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks Jaypal, @user3319181 : when you have posted question you did not mention about the field spacing, it was line spacing, field spacing is different from line spacing, I really don't know the reason for negative vote. Thank you -  Akshay

Comment: @Awk Someone else downvoted. OP doesn't have enough rep to downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another way:

```
awk 'sub(/.$/,sprintf("%03d",NR),$3)' OFS='\t' file
```

**Output:**

```
$ awk 'sub(/.$/,sprintf("%03d",NR),$3)' OFS='\t' file 
ATOM    1       N001    SPINA   3       30.616  29.799  14.979  1.00    20.00   S       N
ATOM    2       N002    SPINA   3       28.146  28.381  13.950  1.00    20.00   S       N
ATOM    3       N003    SPINA   3       27.605  28.239  14.037  1.00    20.00   S       N
ATOM    4       N004    SPINA   3       30.333  29.182  15.464  1.00    20.00   S       N
ATOM    5       N005    SPINA   3       29.608  29.434  14.333  1.00    20.00   S       N
ATOM    6       N006    SPINA   3       29.303  29.830  13.317  1.00    20.00   S       N
ATOM    7       N007    SPINA   3       28.963  31.116  13.472  1.00    20.00   S       N
ATOM    8       N008    SPINA   3       28.859  28.743  13.828  1.00    20.00   S       N
ATOM    9       N009    SPINA   3       29.699  30.575  14.564  1.00    20.00   S       N
ATOM    10      N010    SPINA   3       29.518  29.194  15.301  1.00    20.00   S       N
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interesting to resolve it with pure shell, here is the code:

```
while IFS="\n" read -r line
do     
  n=${line:9:3}
  printf "%sN%03d%s\n" "${line:0:12}" $n "${line:16}"
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$3="N"sprintf("%03d",$2)' OFS='\t' infile.txt
```

Result

```
ATOM    1       N001    SPINA   3       30.616  29.799  14.979  1.00    20.00SN
ATOM    2       N002    SPINA   3       28.146  28.381  13.950  1.00    20.00SN
ATOM    3       N003    SPINA   3       27.605  28.239  14.037  1.00    20.00SN
ATOM    4       N004    SPINA   3       30.333  29.182  15.464  1.00    20.00SN
ATOM    5       N005    SPINA   3       29.608  29.434  14.333  1.00    20.00SN
ATOM    6       N006    SPINA   3       29.303  29.830  13.317  1.00    20.00SN
ATOM    7       N007    SPINA   3       28.963  31.116  13.472  1.00    20.00SN
ATOM    8       N008    SPINA   3       28.859  28.743  13.828  1.00    20.00SN
ATOM    9       N009    SPINA   3       29.699  30.575  14.564  1.00    20.00SN
ATOM    10      N010    SPINA   3       29.518  29.194  15.301  1.00    20.00SN
```